# Issue replacing only the last space of a string

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to replace the last space in a name with a 
 tag. Where I've gotten so far, the last name is simply removed "Amy L. Example" becomes "Amy L."

Any help on this regular expression would be greatly appreciated. Just beginning to grasp how they work.

Code:

```
    <?php $resume['name'] = preg_replace('/\s(\S*)$/', '<br />', $resume['name']); echo $resume['name'] ?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to put `$1` in the replacement string, so that the word you capture will be kept, not removed.

Comment: Incidentally, another way of doing this would be: `preg_replace('/\s(?=\S*$)/','<br />',$resume['name']);` - in this case the word isn't captured, just confirmed with a lookahead, so you don't need the `$1`. I don't know which is more efficient, though.

Answer (score 1):

You're telling PHP to **replace** any non-space character after a space character, placed at the end of your string, with a `<br />`, therefore your `last space + last word` is obviously removed and replaced by just the tag.

Just edit it to this:

```
preg_replace('/\s(\S*)$/', ' \\1<br />', $name);
```

In this way you replace the `last space + last word` with a space, the word itself and the tag.